# What are check and depend attributes in f2py Fortran subroutines?

Tags: fortran, f2py

I am modifying some Fortran code (`f2py`, actually) and I have come across a subroutine like this (https://github.com/dfm/python-nufft/blob/master/nufft/nufft1d.pyf):

```
subroutine nufft1d1f90(nj,xj,cj,iflag,eps,ms,fk,ier) ! in :_nufft:src/nufft1d/nufft1df90.f
    integer, optional,check(len(xj)>=nj),depend(xj) :: nj=len(xj)
    real*8 dimension(nj) :: xj
    complex*16 dimension(nj),depend(nj) :: cj
    integer :: iflag
    real*8 :: eps
    integer :: ms
    complex*16 dimension(ms),intent(out),depend(ms) :: fk
    integer,intent(out) :: ier
end subroutine nufft1d1f90
```

I can guess the basics, but I am not sure exactly what the `check` statement does or how I can possibly modify it. Also, I guess that `depend` somehow tells the compiler that the declared variable depends on some other variable, but what are the consequences of this?

I usually program in Python, or Matlab if I must, but my only experience with Fortran goes 12 years back, so I am very rusty. Somehow Google fails to find anything useful for me and consulting http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-84882-543-7 and http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-85729-233-9 did not turn up anything useful...

Comment: What you are showing is NOT Fortran. It is a .pyf file, a custom language of f2py. Other than that, this site is not for recommending resources. Open your favourite book selling site and search for "Fortran" and read the reviews. Search for "Fortran tutorial" in your favourite search engine. You can also try links in http://fortranwiki.org

Comment: @VladimirF I did actually specify that I was dealing with f2py and I definitely recognise most of the above code as coinciding with possible Fortran code. Come on, reading reviews of Fortran books is very unlikely to tell me if they contain the specific information I am looking for here. The two books that I already checked, as I wrote above, don't. I did search in my favourite search engine and, as I mentioned, I was unable to locate anything useful about these specific details. You seem to indicate that the features I am asking about are f2py-specific, so I can try that direction. Thanks.

Comment: But your question was formulated where to find description of Fortran subroutines, not what the two keywords mean. Therefore it is off-topic. An on topic question is what `check` and `depend` mean in a `.pyf` file, but your question (and especially the title) is not about that.

Comment: OK, corrected now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @VladimirF's comment implied, the right place to look seems to be the documentation of `f2py`. I have found explanations of `check`, `depend` and various other attributes in the [f2py docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/f2py/signature-file.html#attributes).

The `check` attribute is for performing a consistency check on its associated argument. `check` takes a C boolean expression.

The `depend` attribute tells `f2py` that for example the `check` attribute of this argument depends on one or more other arguments. This enables `f2py` to ensure that the arguments are processed in the correct order.